# Select loop in linux - how to make it better?

Tags: c, linux, select, pipe

I have select with N pipe, my problem:
After catch ,,one" `pipe` - select don't work. Probably I don't remove `i`
descriptor. And here is my questions:
1) Do I really have to make dynamic array like `vector` in C and insert and remove `i`
2) How to make my code better? How Can I solve problem with select?

My code:

```
while(1)
        {
                sel = select(val+1,&set,NULL,NULL,&timeout);

                if(sel < 0)
                        perror("Blad funkcji select");
                else if(sel == 0)
                        printf("Brak komunikatow \n");
                else{

                        for(i = 0; i < val; i++)
                        {
                                if(FD_ISSET(fd[i][0],&set))
                                {
                                   while(read(fd[i][0],&buf,rozmiar) > 0)
                                   write(1,&buf,rozmiar);


                                } // check if exist and write to stdout


                } // end SELECT
                for(i = 0, j =0; i< val; i++)
                {
                        FD_SET(fd[i][0], &set);

                }

                timeout.tv_sec = 4;
                timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        }
```

Comment: You need to keep and use the result count of `read`. You should consider using `poll` instead of `select`

Comment: `val+1` is wrong, you need max fd plus one.

Comment: Please, throw away `select()` and use `poll()` instead.  It is just as portable, more efficient, and easier to use.  Notably, you don't have to rebuild the list of interesting fds before every call.  And you don't have to pass in maxfds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> RETURN VALUE         top
>
> ```
>    On success, select() and pselect() return the number of file
>    descriptors contained in the three returned descriptor sets (that is,
>    the total number of bits that are set in readfds, writefds,
>    exceptfds) which may be zero if the timeout expires before anything
>    interesting happens.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set to
>    indicate the error; the file descriptor sets are unmodified, and
>    timeout becomes undefined.
> ```

```
 if(sel ==-1)
                perror("Blad funkcji select");
```

Comment: Ok But how to use it? I Could you show some example of code? I  probably shoulde use sel and remove fd...